# How can I get back to previous page with passing params?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know I can use the below code to go back previous page.

```
$router.go(-1)
```

but is it possible to pass params to the previous page?

Comment: You could store the last address in sessionstorage, and direct to it with query string params.

Comment: Or consider `document.referrer`

Comment: @ZefirZdravkov Ah, I've never seen that before, nice.

Comment: it's a better way to pass through [history.state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method), but unfortunately ```vue-router``` [doesn't support it for now](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1658)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for params in `Vue.js` but you can do it by `document.referrer`

```
window.location = document.referrer + '?index=1';
```